# Continuity of the inverse Laplace Transform

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, laplace-transform, integral-transforms

If I know $Y(s)$,
can I predict when $\mathscr{L}^{-1}[Y(s)]=y(t)$ will be continuous or continuously differentiable or even stronger conditions?

For example; I'm solving an ODE with the Laplace Tranform method so it turns out that the solution is $\mathscr{L}^{-1}[Y(s)]=y(t)$.
How do I know that that function will be countinuously differentiable up to the order of the ODE?

Comment: Note that even a nice function like $e^{-cs}$ transforms under the inverse laplace to a delta function.

Comment: True. But maybe in some particular cases I was wondering if there is a theorem, result or something. Thanks.

Comment: Integration-wise, yes. Differentiation-wise, no(at least to my knowledge).